# Is possible for a customer to change payment method?

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento store where sometimes customers make phone orders, so I enter them into magento and they can pay with a bank transfer no worries.

But is there anyway so client can change a "Pending payment" order to other payment method and perhaps enter for example paypal process?

Looking forward to your reply guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento does not provide this functionality by default. You probably have to write an extension for Magento where your customers get the chance to change the payment method while it's in state pending.

The easier way would be to tell your customers that they have to do the order themselves if they want to use PayPal.